# Intergrate Flutter Web page into existing HTML website

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-html

How to call flutter developed pages in HTML website? I'm seeking for possiblity to use Flutter web page developed in dart in existing HTML website.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option now would be to embed the Flutter Web content in an iFrame.

We're working on enabling embedding content with a page using elements, but that's a ways off.